# NoReverseMatch Reverse for 'by_person' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['people/person/<int:person_pk\\Z']

Tags: django, django-urls

Code from template
Here i extended from basic.html to my people.html

```
{% extends 'laayout/basic.html' %}
{% block content %}

<li><a href="{% url 'people' %}">Main page</a></li>
{% for per in people %}
    <h1><a href="{% url 'by_person'  per.pk %}">{{ per }}</a></h1>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Code from urls:

```
urlpatterns=[

    path('person/<int:person_pk',by_person,name='by_person'),
    path('',people,name='people'),

]
```

code from views:

```
def people(request)->render:
    people=Adult.objects.all()
    template_='people.html'
    context={
    'people':people,
    }
    return render(request,template_,context=context)

     '''
     that how i ve done views
     '''
```

i tried to fix but i got more issues

Comment: I guess that is mainly because of the "sloppy" syntax...

Comment: your url pattern is missing a closing bracket, there was no closing tag for the `{% url ... %}`, there was no `per.pk` parameter. Likely the exception message has changed meanwhile, and you did not share a view. How are people supposed to help you?

Comment: add view function code in question

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem well i ve changed the code,but i still get that error

Answer (score 0):

You need change in url patterns put `pk` only instead of `person_pk`

#### urls.py

urlpatterns=[

```
path('person/<int:pk>/',by_person,name='by_person'),
path('',people,name='people'),
```

]